# apigee command line tool unable to create product for proxy

Tags: apigee

The following command does not work even though there is a proxy by the name income_prediction

```
apigeetool createProduct \
    --approvalType "auto" \
    --environments ${APIGEE_ENVIRONMENT} \
    --proxies income_prediction \
    --productName "income_prediction_trial" \
    --productDesc "Free trial API for income prediction." \
    --quota 10 \
    --quotaInterval 1 \
    --quotaTimeUnit "day"
```

I get an:

```
Error: Create Product failed with status code 403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the mandatory --organization parameter (that specifies the organization you're creating the product for). For some reason, the apigeetool is not asking for it (it should).